# How does array_merge() and + operator work under the hood when merging more than two arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, merge

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php#refsect1-function.array-merge-examples

> If you want to append array elements from the **second array** to the **first array** while not overwriting the elements from the first array and not re-indexing, use the + array union operator:

```
<?php
$array1 = array(0 => 'zero_a', 2 => 'two_a', 3 => 'three_a');
$array2 = array(1 => 'one_b', 3 => 'three_b', 4 => 'four_b');
$result = $array1 + $array2;
var_dump($result);
?>
```

1. How does `array_merge()`(and `+`) work under the hood when merging more than two arrays?

According to my understanding it does the merge between the 2, gives a result (a "temporary" array, something like `SQL JOIN`s) and then now *that resulting one operates with the third one and so on*.

2. Is `array_merge()` therefore a *binary operator*?

> Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values **of one** are appended to the end of the **previous one**. It returns the resulting array.

This question is **only** because I have doubts about **how it operates behind the scenes**.

When I say "binary operator" I mean something that **operates on 2 values**

Comment: "Is array_merge() a binary operator?" is wrong question to ask. "How does array_merge() work under the hood when merging more than two arrays?" is much better

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Here "binary" means "operates on two elements" not "binary" as in encoding or "binary arithmetic". Usually `+` is a "binary operator" by definition, while, say, `!` is unary.

Comment: I'm not sure function calls are ever described as operators on the level of `+`.

Comment: hi @Your Common Sense right, that's the question, I edited,

Comment: Being curious about how PHP works internally is a good thing, but don't forget, it is open-source so you can just look and find out.

Comment: "*Here "binary" means "operates on two elements" not "binary"...*" - @tadman Exactly, that's what I mean in this context

Comment: I have a feeling, based on other languages, that `A + B + C` will work differently from `merge(A,B,C)` as in the first case it's forced to combine A+B, then AB+C. In the second case it knows precisely how many elements the final array will have, so it can do it more efficiently. This is, of course, speculation, so a closer analysis of the code, or some performance testing could help illuminate.

Comment: @Nigel Ren I have already edited the main question

Comment: @OMi Shah No, that question shows examples only between 2 arrays

Comment: @tadman So, to understand these 2 features I think we don't need to know what really happens behind the scenes, just read the documentation, right?. The question was because the doc is mentioned as something thought between 2 arrays.

Comment: Fun fact: The documentation can be wrong or out of date.

Comment: Sure, I've checked it a few times @tadman